# The meaning of ''primary example'

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "Robots are growing in complexity as their use in industry is becoming more widespread. Robots are mainly used in working with automatic machines and equipments. Car production is the ***primary example*** of
>   large and complex robots."

According to these sentences, what does the ***primary example*** mean?

Is it *"chief example"* or *"the first example"*?

Comment: I would suggest that you edit your original question instead of duplicating it http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/103784/car-production-is-the-primary-example-of-robots

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of *primary* in the sentence is *of chief importance*, main.
Car production is the main example of an industry where complex robots are used. Another meaning *the first* (earliest in time or order) has no sense in this sentence.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of "primary" in the sentence is "of chief importance" because the main motif is car production and where the problematic robots are used.

Comment: What do you mean by "problematic"?